# how to get ip address of iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ip-address

I got a webserver up and running in iphone by using [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). But the problem is how can I get the ip address of my iphone/ipad to let the user's know where they can access the server. I found that `[NSHost addresses]` can do the job but I am developing for app store and this is undocumented method.

Comment: How is this a duplicate if the other question doesn't have a marked answer?

Comment: @Morkrom a marked answer is only relevant to one single person: the one who initially wrote the question.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

// Get the INTERNAL ip address

- (NSString *)getIPAddress {

    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL) {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];

                }

            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;

}
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20160527165909/http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-find-ip-address-of-iphone/

Comment: is it officially accepted by Apple?

Comment: @Shivan Raptor  - yes this is officially accepted by apple!

Comment: If I were you, I would use an allocated string, just so that it doesn't stay in memory too long.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saurabh for this sample code, helped me a lot in my current project!

Comment: This method didn't retrieve the iP address when i using LTE / 3G internet connection

Comment: This gives a different ip address than http://www.whatsmyip.org/

Comment: this one works with IPv6, too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125710/how-to-get-ipv6-interface-address-using-getifaddr-function/33127330#33127330

Comment: The ip is different from whatsmyip.org, why?

Comment: Can I change the ip address obtained from this code?

Comment: @AliMohyudin ip address is not something which we can change. It is provided or assigned by ISP or router. You can go for static IP address in setting but you can not change that through code

Comment: @Mathieu, and others who ask why the address given by this method is different to what you get from whatsmyip.org etc. - That's because this method gives your LOCAL IP address. That is, the IP which other devices on your local area network (home hub, WiFi network, office intranet etc.) will use to talk to your device. These addresses usually start with 10. or 192.168. which marks them out as internal, un-routeable from the internet addresses. WhatsMyIP.org gives your EXTERNAL IP address, which is your local network gateway address, and all of the devices on your local area network share it.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted. This method gives the local IP address instead of your public ip which you will get when you search " my ip" in google. I wanted the local wifi ip and this code works great.

Comment: @Saurabh feel free to rollback my edit once your blog is fixed

Comment: @Cœur thanks .. i will fix all the links by tomorrow..

Comment: returns error always :(

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: wouldn't it be better to break the loop after you acquired the address?

Answer (score -1):

I believe `[NSHost address];` is documented, it's listed here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Use `[[NSHost currentHost] address];` to get the IP.

Comment: its available for Mac OS ... not for iOS!!

Comment: Avoid using NSHost: it's not thread safe. It must be run on the main thread, it's blocking and not deterministic. I've had an obvious-but-hard-to-explain deadlock thanks to it :(

Comment: This is available on iOS 8.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, I'm I missing something? I can't seem to get this working with iOS 8

Comment: @JohnRiselvato I'm not sure what's going on. I was using NSHost on iOS 8 in August, but I ended up removing that feature from my app. Typing NSHost into `file -> open quickly` brings up NSStream.h but then that file doesn't contain a definition for the class. Weird. Perhaps Apple accidentally switched it from a private API to a public one, then reversed it?

Comment: @Jesse, How can you say that? [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/) is saying **Available in OS X v10.0 and later**

Comment: @MrugeshTank: I think Jesse is speaking about iOS and not Mac OS X

Comment: @Yogi, Yes but he said it's available in iOS also. So I forwarded link of Apple Docs which is saying that available in OS X (no sign of iOS).