# How can i track application level network usage including requested URL's IP address in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7

I read an answer about getting sent and received packet data under [iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Now i would like to have the following at application level:

- Requested URL's IP Address from application
- Packets i am receiving
- Packets i am sending
- Total usage of network by that particular application
- Current State of connection for that application

Is it possible to have the above ?

Answer (score 0):

- For total network usage of application I'd create a custom URLProtocol(http://www.raywenderlich.com/59982/nsurlprotocol-tutorial) and count bytes there.
- For current connection state you can use [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability).
- [This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/ResolvingDNSHostnames.html) can help to resolve DNS names into ip-addresses. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807788/how-to-get-ip-address-of-iphone-programatically) also may help.
- I'm not sure about packets for your particular app, AFAIK it's not possible. In linked question you can see how to get statistics for all interfaces, maybe that can be the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try the above things, plus if you want to test against network conditions also then you can try **Network link conditioner**.
Here's a link to get started http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/