# xcode Swift flag - reading #define

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to to read in the ip address of the build machine from a flag. The solution is working for Objc: [How to get current computer's IP address in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218518/how-to-get-current-computers-ip-address-in-xcode)

Note: I am not looking for the plist answer, but the one using:

```
export SERVER_IP=`ipconfig getifaddr en0`
```

But how to set and read a defined value in Swift?

Thanks