# Determine link layer physical media type

Tags: c, linux, networking, ethernet

Using [**`getifaddrs`**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getifaddrs), we can iterate over all the available network interfaces on a machine.  For this question, I'm only concerned with layer 2 (link layer) interfaces - i.e. interfaces of the `AF_PACKET` family.

When we are iterating over all the interfaces returned from `getifaddrs`, and we find a `struct ifaddrs` instance whose `ifa_addr->sa_family` field is `AF_PACKET`, it seems we still need further information about what type of layer 2 interface we are dealing with.

We can rule out loopback interfaces and point-to-point interfaces by checking the `ifa_flags` field.  But apart from that, how can we tell if a particular `AF_PACKET` interface is Ethernet, or something else?  Presumably, it could also be some other Layer 2 technology, like WiFi, token-ring, or Bluetooth.  So how can we tell if it is Ethernet or something else?

Reading the [documentation for `struct sockaddr_ll`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/packet), it appears there is a field `sll_protocol` that contains "the standard ethernet protocol type in network byte order".  This confuses me a bit, because now I'm unsure whether `sockaddr_ll` is supposed to only be used for Ethernet, or whether it's supposed to be used as a generic link layer socket object.  The fact that the documentation says that `sll_protocol` contains the standard *ethernet* protocol indicates to me that `sockaddr_ll` is supposed to only be used for Ethernet.  But yet the `sll_addr` field seems to be more generic (it can contain a length up to 8 bytes, instead of just a 6 byte MAC address).

I'm also unsure if the family `AF_PACKET` itself is what is supposed to tell me that the physical media must be Ethernet.

The only other clue I can find on how to do this comes from http://www.microhowto.info/howto/get_the_mac_address_of_an_ethernet_interface_in_c_using_siocgifhwaddr.html.  This seems to imply that by using the older `struct ifreq` and `ioctl` interface, along with `SIOCGIFHWADDR`, you can definitely tell if a particular interface is Ethernet by checking the `sa_family` field of the `ifr_hwaddr` field in the `ifreq` struct.  If the device is an Ethernet device, the `sa_family` field should be set to `ARPHRD_ETHER`.

But I'm confused as to why this is not consistent with `getifaddrs`, where the `ifa_addr->sa_family` field is simply `AF_PACKET` for layer 2 Ethernet interfaces.  It seems this newer API (`getifaddrs`) doesn't provide any way to distinguish if a particular network interface is actually Ethernet, versus some other Layer 2 technology like WIFI.

So what is the best way determine if a particular network interface is Ethernet (as opposed to some other Layer 2 technology)?

Comment: I think `getifaddrs` is supposed to work with IEEE 802. And I suspect the "ethernet" is the IEEE 802.3 standard. For ipv6 (is ipv6 also ethernet/) there is EUI-64, which takes 8 bytes, not EUI-48. `how can you determine if a particular network interface is Ethernet` - can you define what is Ethernet?

Comment: I would define Ethernet as IEEE 802.3

Answer (score 0):

We can just check `ifa_addr->sa_family` value and I think it is supposed to give you the procotol layer 2. There are some cool answers on stackoverflow, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125710/how-to-get-ipv6-interface-address-using-getifaddr-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248681/9072753) that use `getifaddrs`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

        struct ifaddrs *ifa;

        if (getifaddrs(&ifa) == -1) {
            perror("getifaddrs failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (struct ifaddrs *i = ifa; i; i = i->ifa_next) {
                printf("Name %s has ", i->ifa_name);
                if (i->ifa_addr == NULL) {
                        printf("no address!");
                } else if (i->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                        printf("ipv4 (ie. ethernet, ie. IEEE 802.3)");
                } else if (i->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
                        printf("ipv6");
                } else if (i->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_BLUETOOTH) {
                        printf("bluetooth");
                } else {
                        printf("unhandled!");
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: So does `AF_PACKET` always indicate Ethernet (IEEE 802.3) then?

Comment: `AF_PACKET` is like your own protocol / no protocol. It's a "packet" protocol - there are packets (nothing more). AF_INET is ipv4.

Comment: So if `AF_PACKET` is supposed to be just a "generic packet protocol", how does checking the `family` tell you if an interface is Ethernet?  If `ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET`, are you guaranteed the interface is Ethernet?  Or could it be something else, like WIFI for example?